# Does bootstrap popover have a DOM loaded event, or equivalent way to find out?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I'm creating a bootstrap popover in javascript on an element, and I need to do some work after the popover DOM has been written. I have the following so far.

```
                // bootstrap popover
                element.popover({
                    title: scope.title,
                    content: content.data,
                    placement: "bottom",
                    html: true
                }).on("show.bs.popover", function () {
                    console.log("this is still before the node is in the DOM");
                });
```

So i'm setting title, html content, and placement. However, the html content contains an angular `<directive>` that I wish to `$compile()` and bootstrap doesn't add the node to the DOM until after the click event.

What I want to do, is when the node appears on the page, run a function that processes the html inside the popover.

Any ideas? Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

answering my own question I can do:

```
.on("shown.bs.popover", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("aria-describedby");
    var popover = $("#"+id);
});
```

This gets me the popover html, which I can then run $compile on.